# Django proxy model and AuditTrail

Tags: django, audit-trail

I have a model from which I have created a proxy model so that I can override get_query_set method of the default 'objects' manager. The model implements [AuditTrail](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AuditTrail) but the proxy ignores it -- which is not what I want. I want a save() via the proxy model to update the audit trail just like the model.

```
class SubjectConsent(BaseSubjectConsent):

    history = AuditTrail() 


class SubjectConsentY1(SubjectConsent):

    objects = SubjectY1Manager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Is this behaviour expected? That is, are the managers of the model not available to the proxy?

My custom manager looks like this:

```
class SubjectY1Manager(models.Manager):

   def get_query_set(self):

        return QuerySet(self.model, using=self._db).filter(survey__survey_slug = 'mpp-year-0')
```

Comment: Better show some more code as this should be the correct way to this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-model-managers . Maybe there's something wrong with the manager's implementation... EDIT: Sorry after reading your question again: `save()` is actually not a manager method! You could try to override the proxy model's default save method and explicitly try to call it on the parent class...

Comment: the save() method of the model is called when saving an instance of the proxy model. I suspect this has to do more with the way AuditTrail is implemented

Comment: Do you have an `objects` manager on `SubjectConsent` or just `history`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

..self.answer...The intention is to get AuditTrail to update the audit trail for the model, SubjectConsent, via an instance of the proxy model. Through normal model class inheritance, managers are not inherited. I am not sure if this also applies to the "proxy model" design but in my case the AuditTrail manager is not present in the proxy model.

Adding "history = AuditTrail()" to the proxy model causes an error as AuditTrail adds itself to the proxy model using the same attributes of the model.

so, all i could come up with for now is to get an instance of the model and call it's save() method after super(SubjectConsentY1, self).save(). It is an extra call to the DB but, in this way, the audit trail is updated via an instance of the proxy model.

```
class SubjectConsent(BaseSubjectConsent):

    history = AuditTrail() 


class SubjectConsentY1(SubjectConsent):

    objects = SubjectY1Manager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # call super save() method to update the DB and get a pk
        super(SubjectConsentY1, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # get instance of model and save to update the audit trail
        SubjectConsent.objects.get(pk=self.pk).save()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```